# Para que sirve el archivo .gitkeep

Tags: git

me surgió la duda, ya que encontré en una librería que descargue un archivo `.gitkeep`, el cual se encontraba vació. Aunque estuve buscando en la documentación de GIT no pude encontrar el uso del mismo.

Alguien sabe si se usa para algo o solo fue creada por el autor sin un fin especifico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si creas una nueva carpeta en un proyecto bajo control de versiones con Git, veras que al hacer un **git status**, no aparece, mientras está vacía.

Una forma de añadir cartetas vacías en tu repositorio sería añadir un fichero en su interior. **Por convenio se usa un .gitkeep**, por eso no es un fichero 'oficial' de Git, y si quieres puedes poner un fichero llamado '.pepito-palotes' (o el que te de la gana, aunque el primero se este imponiendo).

En esta página se explica con detalle: http://aprendegit.com/gitkeep-incluyendo-carpetas-en-los-repositorios/
Un saludo.

Answer (score 6):

El archivo `.gitkeep` es solo un archivo dummy para permitir que una carpeta vacía (excepto por ese archivo) se cree al clonar el repositorio, ya que las carpetas vacías no forman parte del control de versiones.

En realidad el archivo puede llamarse de cualquier manera pero esa es una convención no oficial adoptado por algunos

Comment: Mi voto va para este respuesta, simplemente por el orden cronologico

Comment: en realidad se esta crea un archivo vacio para que git cree la carpeta con un archivo que el usuario no va a ver